# Are small deeds enough to go into jannah?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jannah

As we know there are hadith like, if you recite ayatul kursi after every prayer you will go to jannah.
And also there is another hadith, that there is a dua if you recite that after wudu then you will get 8 gates of paradise.
But the problem is my friend is saying, if doing only these will lead us to jannah then we don't need to do other deeds or we only need to do very few deeds.
So please answer this.

Comment: See also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16593/13438) which is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Of course with only small deeds you will be going to *Jannah* eventually. What matters here is **when and how fast** are you going to enter *Jannah*? The more good deeds you do, the faster Allah will let you inside. However, if your bad side suppress your goodness, then you will need longer time before entering *Jannah*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes only Small deeds can leed you to jaanah and divine love of Allah but the main thing is you should stay away from prohibition of Islam
Never hurt anybody physically,mentally or spiritually!
Stay away from Haram,never miss your faraiz and you would surely go to that divine heavenly life

Comment: But for that my friend saying we don't need to do anymore deeds. and that's a problem. we should do good deeds as much as possible. shouldn't we?